# Use a range of values with a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following queries;

```
$sel_referrals1="SELECT t1.referree AS GEN1, t2.referree as GEN2, t3.referree as GEN3, t4.referree as GEN4, t5.referree as GEN5, t6.referree as GEN6, t7.referree as GEN7, t8.referree as GEN8, t9.referree as GEN9, t10.referree as GEN10, t11.referree as GEN11
                                        FROM referrals AS t1
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t2 ON t2.referrer = t1.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t3 ON t3.referrer = t2.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t4 ON t4.referrer = t3.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t5 ON t5.referrer = t4.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t6 ON t6.referrer = t5.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t7 ON t7.referrer = t6.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t8 ON t8.referrer = t7.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t9 ON t9.referrer = t8.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t10 ON t10.referrer = t9.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t11 ON t11.referrer = t10.referree
                                        WHERE t1.referrer = '{$_SESSION['user']}'";
$selected1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_referrals1);
$selected_levels= mysqli_fetch_array($selected1);
```

I wanted to process the results of the query as in the following statement;

```
$select_level1="SELECT SUM(amount) FROM topup WHERE user_id IN('{$selected1['GEN1']}')";//The is line 80
 $selected_level1 = mysqli_query($conn,$select_level1);
 $result_level1 = mysqli_fetch_row($selected_level1);
 $level1=number_format($result_level1[0],2);
```

However, i get the following error;

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in D:\xampp2\htdocs\airtimez\referrals.php on line 80

Help me debug it

Comment: @chris85, thanks very much for your keen look on my error. Now, $selected_levels seems to return only one value(row). I expected $selected1['GEN1'] to hold an array of values.Actually it should hold  (12, 13 ,17 ,18 ,19, 28)

Comment: Actually it should hold (12, 13 ,17 ,18 ,19, 28). Such that the query actually should be like; SELECT SUM(amount) FROM topup WHERE user_id IN (12, 13 ,17 ,18 ,19, 28) ;

Comment: Posted an untested answer below. Comment if you have questions/issues; if not and it resolves the issue please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$selected1['GEN1']` the `$selected1` is a result object, not the fetched results, you fetch with `$selected_levels`.
2. To fetch multiple rows the `fetch` needs to be looped `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selected1))`.
3. You should not put variables into a SQL query, this will open you to SQL injections. Instead use parameterized queries.
4. If you only need the `id`s to get the `sum` just use a subquery.

Roughly:

```
$sel_referrals1="SELECT SUM(amount) as da_sum FROM topup WHERE user_id IN((SELECT t1.referree
                                        FROM referrals AS t1
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t2 ON t2.referrer = t1.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t3 ON t3.referrer = t2.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t4 ON t4.referrer = t3.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t5 ON t5.referrer = t4.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t6 ON t6.referrer = t5.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t7 ON t7.referrer = t6.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t8 ON t8.referrer = t7.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t9 ON t9.referrer = t8.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t10 ON t10.referrer = t9.referree
                                        LEFT JOIN referrals AS t11 ON t11.referrer = t10.referree
                                        WHERE t1.referrer = ?))";
$selected1 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sel_referrals1);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selected1, 'i', $_SESSION['user']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selected1);
while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($selected1)){ 
     echo number_format($row['da_sum'], 2);
}
```

Although you also might want to `group` the sums by `userid`.

Comment: aaw, what a help @chris85. Thank you so much